# How to map a table with composite key with one of the column being foreign key on Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I am having a hard time mapping the following database schema on Hibernate:

[image: database schema]

The `tb_order` is an existing table and it is already mapped on Java class. The `tb_external_order_details` table was recently created and it only have two columns. Both columns are part of the composite Primary Key. The `tb_order_id` column references to the `id` column on `tb_order` table and the `external_order_id` is just a loose id that doesn't references any column on database.

Please note that the database table and column names are not exactly equal to the Java classes and attributes names. e.g. the java class name is `Order` and the table name is `tb_order`. I just think this is important to note because the table/column names inferred by Hibernate may not match (also the table column is snake_case while properties on java classes will be camelCase).

I tried many solutions found here on stack overflow and none of them worked. Also, on the examples I found, no column of the composite Primary Key is a Foreign Key referencing another column of another table.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64351432/6277104) will help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Entity
public class Order {
    @Id
    Integer id;
    String type;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order")
    Set<ExternalOrderDetails> externalOrderDetails;
}
@Entity
public class ExternalOrderDetails {
    @EmbeddedId
    ExternalOrderDetailsId id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tb_order_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    Order order;
}
@Entity
public class ExternalOrderDetailsId {
    @Column(name = "tb_order_id")
    Integer orderId;
    @Column(name = "external_order_id")
    Integer externalOrderId;
}
```

Comment: The two first classes are called ExternalOrderDetails. Can you please check?

Comment: I adapted it for you